# C# unit tests: Is it OK to use conditional access instead of Debug.Assert?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

So I have the following unit test for a controller action (MVC 5). The purpose of the test is to ensure that the Edit action of the controller returns a model of type `Contact`:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Edit_ValidContactIdPassed_ShouldReturnEditViewWithContact()
    {
        var result = _controller.Edit(1) as ViewResult;
        result?.ViewData.Model.Should().BeOfType<Contact>();
    }
```

As you can see I am using the conditional access(?) on the `result` object instead of:

```
        Debug.Assert(result != null, "result != null");
```

I believe the conditional access is more readable but is there any issues with this within the context of a unit test?

Comment: Looks like this question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends on what your test is testing. If the specification says that there must always be a result, then checking for null may hide an error.

Comment: What is the purpose of this test ? Really read how to build proper method names.

Comment: Also, Debug.Assert and Assert.IsNotNull are different things.

Comment: There is not need for conditional access or Debug.Assert. For me this test needs two assertions (assuming you are using FluentAssertions): 1. result.Should().NotBeNull(); 2. result.ViewData.Model.Should().BeOfType<Contact>();

(Note: If your are a fan of the One-Assert-Per-Test approach make two tests out of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are testing the `var result` and test must be **negative** if it is `== null` in this case you will prevent the error from being fired as with the conditional access you prevent a potential `NullPointerException`

```
Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

It's not that bad after all :)!